# ASP.NET Web Api controller discovery caching period

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, controller

I'm loading many controllers from different folders in my Web Api project with custom assembly resolver. My problem is that service calls take too long time. For first call it's OK because all controller loading related staff goes there and following service calls take short time as expected, but after about 1 hour of inactive Api(no service calls are made) first call takes too long time again, maybe controller discovery process occurs again?

How long period is needed for api to "reload" controller information? Or is it loaded only once at first service call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is that your website is idle for more than 20mins (the default), so IIS unloads it from memory, therefore, the first request after the website has been unloaded from memory takes a bit of time as IIS is loading the website back into memory, this is also known as warming up the site.

You can keep your website warm/in memory for a longer period of time by changing the 'Idle time-out' property of your websites Application Pool, you'll find this setting under the 'Process Model' section of advanced application pool settings.

Alternatively, if you're using IIS 8.0 you can take advantage of Application Initialization which will allow you to set your application pool to 'Always Running'.

Comment: Thanks man! now it makes sense why is the first call slow, I think after process recycling controller discovery staff occurs again. I'm gonna log it and see what happens.